# WDT timeout in iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, timeout, kernel, watchdog

I have been struggling to solve a crash in an iPhone app that is affecting mostly users with older devices, suggesting it is somehow linked to hardware processing power. The app records and analyzes sound over night, and the crash typically occurs after 2-4 hours running. The crash produces no crash report with stack trace and is not preceded by memory warnings.

The crash is producing this WDT timeout error, which I can find very little information on and am struggling to discern any clues from. Can anybody help interpret anything from it or have any general tips as to what kind of processes/conflicts could cause a crash of this kind to occur? Any suggestions on how best to proceed?

```
Incident Identifier: DB5B12FF-D03E-45FE-A32D-9A62EE4490E0
CrashReporter Key:   1a40ef56e27368d8790606ed1a4315bc65dc95c4
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Date/Time:           2014-04-22 17:40:22.374 +0100
OS Version:          iOS 7.1 (11D169)

Debugger message: WDT timeout
33s ago: 3963m0/0 3963m0/1 3963u0 3863m0/0 3863m0/1 3863u0 3763m0/0 3763m0/1 3763u0 3662m0/0 3659m0/1 3659u0 3558m0/0 3558m0/1 3558u0 3458m0/0 3458m0/1 3458u0 3357m0/0 3357m0/1 3357u0 3257m0/0 3255m0/1 3255u0 3152m0/0 3130m0/1 3130u0 3030m0/0 3030m0/1 3030u0 2929m0/0 2923m0/1 2923u0 2822m0/0 2734m0/1 2734u0 2564m0/0 2549m0/1 2549u0 2443m0/0 2437m0/1 2437u0 2237m10004003/0 2075u0 2074m0/1 2074u0 1874m10004003/0 1802u0 1801m0/1 1801u0 1691m0/0 1591m10004003/1 1202u0 1202u0 1054m0/0 1054m0/1 1054u0 854m10004003/0 601u0 600m0/1 600u0 400m10004003/0 0tffc00 0m0/1 
OS version: 11D169
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Fri Feb 21 19:41:10 PST 2014; root:xnu-2423.10.67~1/RELEASE_ARM_S5L8930X
Kernel slide:     0x0000000003a00000
Kernel text base: 0x83a01000
  Boot    : 0x5355a1fd 0x00000000
  Sleep   : 0x53563d27 0x00065d6a
  Wake    : 0x53563d74 0x000001d2
  Calendar: 0x53569b1c 0x0004f49b

Total cpu_usage: 15404741
Thread task pri cpu_usage
0xc5c78110 MY APP 97 5153490
0xc5329330 kernel_task 93 2287
0xc493de90 kernel_task 81 823
0xc499ce90 kernel_task 81 5625
0xc5fa57d0 mediaserverd 60 7288

Panicked task 0xc4810830: 8899 pages, 12 threads: pid 864: MY APP
panicked thread: 0xc5c78110, backtrace: 0x83d32b10
        0x83b189f1
        0x83b195e7
        0x83f071f7
        0x842d7cff
        0x83a99857
        0x83a1ca0c

Task 0xc4819c00: 12615 pages, 113 threads: pid 0: kernel_task
Task 0xc4819950: 271 pages, 3 threads: pid 1: launchd
Task 0xc48193f0: 1221 pages, 11 threads: pid 14: UserEventAgent
Task 0xc4819140: 1049 pages, 5 threads: pid 15: wifid
Task 0xc4818930: 660 pages, 3 threads: pid 18: timed
Task 0xc4818120: 787 pages, 4 threads: pid 21: mediaremoted
Task 0xc4817910: 544 pages, 2 threads: pid 24: iaptransportd
Task 0xc4817100: 309 pages, 2 threads: pid 27: softwareupdated
Task 0xc4816e50: 2723 pages, 14 threads: pid 28: backboardd
Task 0xc4816640: 961 pages, 2 threads: pid 31: fairplayd.H1
Task 0xc48160e0: 619 pages, 3 threads: pid 33: mDNSResponder
Task 0xc4815e30: 9582 pages, 14 threads: pid 34: SpringBoard
Task 0xc4815b80: 913 pages, 2 threads: pid 35: routined
Task 0xc48158d0: 492 pages, 3 threads: pid 36: softwarebehavior
Task 0xc4815370: 1044 pages, 7 threads: pid 38: aggregated
Task 0xc48148b0: 252 pages, 6 threads: pid 42: syslogd
```